# Start activity

Tags: android, eclipse

when i tryed to start activity when phone stops ringing and it force closes all the time.

so here's my broadcast reciever

```
public class Incoming extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         MyPhoneStateListener phoneListener=new MyPhoneStateListener();  
            TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)   
            arg0.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
         phoneListener.context = arg0;
            telephony.listen(phoneListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);  
    }

}
```

And this should start activity

```
public class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {  

    int prevstate;


    public void onCallStateChanged(int state,String incomingNumber){  


        if(prevstate==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK && state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE){

              Log.i("PARm","Here the activity should start");
          }
        else if(prevstate==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING && state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE){ 

            Log.i("PARM","Here the activity should start");

        }



    switch(state){  
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:  
          Log.d("DECallNoteActivity.get getContext();BUG", "IDLE"); 
          prevstate = state;
        break;  
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:  
          Log.d("DEBUG", "OFFHOOK");
          prevstate = state;
        break;  
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:  
          Log.d("DEBUG", "RINGING");
          prevstate = state;
        break;  
        }

      } 


    }
```

i would be pleased if you could tell me how to get context in this case to start Activity or another way how to start it.

Thank you.

Comment: Please post any logcat errors.

Comment: How is your BroadcastReceiver set up? Using <receiver> tag in the manifest or using Context.registerReceiver() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The broadcast receiver's context is only valid for the duration of the `onReceive` call: you can't save it and reuse it later. If you need to start an Activity this way what you will need to so is start a `Service` from the `BroadcastReceiver`'s `onReceive` method, and have that service create the phone state listener and launch the required `Activity`: once it has launched the `Activity` it can stop itself.